# IN statement multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, sql-in

I want to implement the below query

```
Select * from table1
where a in(select a,b,c,d,e from table2 order by date desc limit 5)
```

But IN statement is allowing only 1 column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you need to do this suggests your design could use a rethink.  But assuming the goal is to compare "a" from table1 separately to each column's value for table2, you can do it like this:

```
 ... in (select unnest(array[a,b,c,d,e]) from (select * from table2 order by date limit 5) foo )
```

Comment: The following error is occurring; ERROR:  `subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 1: ..." where a in(select unnest(array[a,b,c,d,e]) from (select * ...
                                                             ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
SQL state: 42601
Character: 79`

Comment: Fixed.  The dummy alias isn't needed in the current dev version ( the future v16) which I tested with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the where clause in following

```
Select * from table1
where (a,a,a,a,a) in(select a,b,c,d,e from table2 order by date desc limit 5)
```

Comment: Based on the above query, the outcome is 0. As @jjanes mentioned, basically I want to compare "a" from table1 separately to each column's value for table2